# Infopath: sum (non-bound) calculated values

Tags: infopath, calculated-column

Infopath & Sharepoint 2010, list Form:

I have 2 calculated values placed on infoPath form.
Those fields are not bound to existing list fields as I don't need store this data, just present to user.

Question is if **I can sum both in 3rd calculated field ?** (this time bound to field).

For now, I'm just repeating 2 fx calculation in 3rd calculated value.
I wonder if I can enter something like calc_val_1 +  calc_val_2 in 3rd calc.value formula...

Comment: Thanks for marking my answer but I feel I missed the target point so I updated my prev answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. In Infopath, OOTB,  it is possible to access only data (from data sources or data fields) not control's values.

- **Update:**
  And **calculated value** control in Infopath has an expression (based on values of other data fields or data sources) as its data source but is not and cannot be (without converting it to another type of control) bound to a "its own" data ( field).
  And its binding to a data field will make from a calculated-value control a non-calculated-value control, i.e. something different.

PS
And the last statement should not be misunderstood, it is possible to format (change visual appearance of) controls OOTB (through the rules or Infopath Designer GUI), i.e. by provided in Infopath Designer means.
But, AFAIK, it is impossible, for example, to get a reference to object of control in codebehind and one can access controls only implicitly - [navigating to data nodes bound to them](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50464/how-to-insert-a-named-hyperlink-anchor-in-infopath/50474#50474).